# Algorithm for packing rectangles with minimum amount of loss and most similar space (for multi user video room)

Tags: algorithm, bin-packing

I'm building a multi user conference room and I want all of my users coming from both mobile and desktop, so both portrait and landscape orientation, to have a roughly equal amount of space dedicated to their feed, without cutting off too much or adding too many bars. The screen they need to be packed in also can be portrait and landscape.

Since we're limiting the amount of users to 5 I can actually just hard code the ideal layout and be done with it under an hour, allowing for some inefficiency but it would work well enough in all circumstances, but I am curious how to do it with an algorithm.

What I've found so far are algorithms that pack fixed size rectangles and leave some space where rectangles wouldn't fit. What I'm looking for is an algorithm that does the following:

- Rectangles should be as close to their original ratio as possible
- Rectangles original size is irrelevant, just their ratio
- The resulting sizes should be as similar as possible
- No space should be left unused
- Programming language is irrelevant, but I will implement it in Swift to begin with

Comment: If this is user-facing, the problem seems not only bound by space considerations. There's also an aesthetic aspect.

Comment: You are right, I have to decide after getting the most ideal rectangles on when to use black bars instead of filling up the rectangle. Probably if you start losing more than 30% by using aspect fill it's time to go to aspect fill, but that's something that's not a huge concern now.